# Ubuntu 14 spontaneously restart

Tags: reboot, ubuntu-14.04

my Ubuntu 14 desktop with server was spontaneously restart. It was happened 12. jan 2017 12:14 (checked from console by "last reboot"). It seems to be more power consumption by kern.log. Which settings have I set to prevent spontaneously restart PC? Thanks

[kern.log](https://justpaste.it/12ci6)

EDIT: Added "cat /proc/cpuinfo" output to file cpuinfo

[cpuinfo](https://justpaste.it/12cm4)

EDIT2: Added output from "last reboot"

> reboot   system boot  3.13.0-107-gener Thu Jan 12 12:14 - 16:28  (04:13)
>   reboot   system boot  3.13.0-106-gener Wed Jan  4 16:48 - 16:28 (7+23:39)
>
> wtmp begins Wed Jan  4 16:48:24 2017

Answer (score 0):

The log doesn't show any indications on what caused the crash at 12:14.

Stuff like this happens, from time to time (I'd say my box crashes about once every 6 months). Make sure you're updating the system (especially the kernel), try performing a memcheck (checking for bad ram).

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/129125/how-to-diagnose-a-spontaneous-reboot?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for info, it's might be a update of kernel? Because I paste to question a output from console "last reboot", where is different generation of kernel probably. Can I set this to confirm restart before update kernel?

Comment: Well, if the machine crashes (and restarts!) then it will automatically start with the lastes, greatest kernel.