# PC randomly freezing then going black before rebooting

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, freeze, black-screen-of-death

I got my prebuilt pc (after having carefully chosen the specs) around June last year and a few weeks in I started getting random black screens with audio etc still playing in the background. I talked with those who made it for me before it miraculously stopped happening (possibly due to a Ryzen Software update) aside the rare occurrence. Recently its started back up with it freezing then going black, often coupled with a restart.

My PC specs are:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor 3.59 GHz
- GPU: AMD Ryzen RX 5700
- 16GB of RAM.
- 1 Terabyte SSD

I have read people with [similar issues](https://superuser.com/questions/129125/how-to-diagnose-a-spontaneous-reboot) but mine seems different as it's a relatively fresh build, The PC was built by:*PC Specialist*. I appreciate any advice you can offer, is this the same issue as a few months ago, is it hardware despite being relatively new; Thank you.

*A couple notes:
- PC may briefly appear or flicker.
- Audio continues
- PC continues to whir.
- I do have a slightly finicky wire attached to one of my monitors; which when shifted can lose signal to BOTH monitors. 
- ...I have two monitors.
- Generally happens when gaming, pc is within a healthy range when playing with GPU at around 50%*

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

I have Enhanced Sync ***OFF*** due to known black screen related issues,
My event viewer at time of crash:
[Event Viewer Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWRNC.png)

**UPDATE/EDIT:**

During further testing it crashed but managed to recover without a forced restart. Thanks to this I believe the issue is with driver: ***amdkmdap*** 
After receiving the following Warning: *Display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered.*

**That said, the requested Driver is not showing up when searched for:**

[Driver Verifier Manager Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjjaA.png)

Comment: Anything in the system logs before the crash? Can you check which version of drivers do you've installed for GPU (do you've the latest ones)?

Comment: Hia Thank you, I do have the latest Driver and Software Update for my GPU,

Comment: Event Viewer Errors: The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000116 (0xffff9b03b0ca6460, 0xfffff800310b09f0, 0x0000000000000000, 0x000000000000000d). A dump was saved in: C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 8d8895bc-4668-4b1b-86f9-a6be4e87fb7c. - This sems the most useful error I have, appearing after the "Critical" error which shut my pc, I have several errors and warnings just before this ("Critical") that I can post as well. Not 100% sure what i'm looking for; first time I've opened event viewer. @kenorb

Comment: @kenorb I have updated the post with a photo of the event viewer and am happy to elaborate on any other of the errors etc at your request.

Comment: It looks and sounds like overheating to me.

Comment: @Didier A possibility, I keep the PC in a PC Pocket under my desk with walls either side and under. That said it's got plenty of room: Front, Back (A couple inches) and Top (Several Inches) - I also got some extra fans and ventilated casing to combat this. Is it likely to be this despite? Appreciate to hear what you and a third party have to say.

Comment: You can try to set it in the open, with plenty of airflow around, and see how it does. If you don't get any more of those crashes, you'll have found what was (probably) causing them.

Comment: @Didier, I have taken it out and places it in an open space (as of writing GPU temp is: 50C), but still crashed and rebooted. I did a memory check but it restarted without displaying the results after (do you know how I can check this?). Any other suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Sad to learn it wasn't that simple. Press the Windows key on your keyboard, and type "memory". You should see an entry called "Memory Diagnostics". Right-click on it, choose "Run as administrator", and you should access the results of your memtest in the Memory section of Event VIewer.

Comment: @Didier Doesn't appear there were any memory issues ( I redid the test and watched live results as I couldn't find the memtest). What else would you recommend? The recurring error seems to be: 'Session "dfa2c640-651d-488d-a479-2fd7a7ca6e29" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000022'

Comment: This seems to be intimately related to gaming (see all the topics here: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Session+%22dfa2c640-651d-488d-a479-2fd7a7ca6e29%22+failed+to+start+with+the+following+error%3A+0xC0000022), so one or several of the fixes proposed in those topics could help you. One says to add the directory where you keep your games to Windows Defender's list of to-watch directories, an other suggests to thoroughly clean your preferences for the game in question. All points to AMD, though, apparently.

Comment: @Didier I have looked through these extensively before and briefly just now, none of these forums have any clear fix or suggestions from what I can see. I may just being thick so if there are any good forums please do send them over the airwaves. I'm looking at my Virus and Threat Protection page and can't see anything related to 'to watch directories' - Sidenote: my main antivirus provider is bitdefender.

Comment: I think your problem might have several causes that, collectively, lead to what you're experiencing. You might want to take all those steps one at a time, but take them all eventually. It's linked to graphics memory somehow, but it's hard to pinpoint ONE reason for this to happen. For example, if you temporarily disable BitDefender while gaming, does it still happen? If you uninstall the game(s) that seem to cause it and clean-install them again, does it help? Etc... Apparently, only AMD-based machines seem concerned by this, from what I've read. Worth asking them directly, too.

Comment: Mhm, I'm a big AMD fan since Intel stagnated. I've whitelisted all Game directories from bitdefender and will try Watch Dogs 2. Interestingly I've only experienced this issue with CS:GO (which I played for a week, don't hate on me) and WD2.

Comment: @Didier It appears likely to be a driver issue as during testing it crashed but recovered without restarting, with the following warning: "Display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered."

Comment: Well, you got your answer. Now, if this driver keeps on crashing on you, it could mean many things: not enough power coming to your GPU when under strain, a too-high fps during your gaming, etc... Troubleshooting is about being methodical.

Comment: Thank you, I've been told it's likely down to motherboard issues so have updated all the drivers - but it's still happening. How would I fix the GPU issue which appears to be the cause. (So lucky it managed to recover that one time to highlight the issue).